# Learning Nodejs, issues with callbacks and fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am learning Nodejs for school and running into a slight issue with callbacks and fs.readFile(). Unfortunately, I must strictly use native Nodejs modules for this assignment.

I am trying to read a plain text file containing user data asynchronously.

Here what I've got so far:

```
// node_modules/user/index.js
modules.exports = {
  all: function() {
    fs.readFile(users_file, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var users = {};
      var lines = (""+data).split("\n");
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var col = 0;
        var csv = lines[i].split(",");
        var data = {
          id: csv[++col],
          firstName: csv[++col],
          lastName: csv[++col],
          emailAddress: csv[++col],
          phoneNumber: csv[++col]
        };
        users[""+i] = new User(data);
      }
      console.log(users);
      return users;
    });
  }
}
```

The output of console.log(users); is correct, however this always returns undefined.

Comment: Out of interest, why is users not an array?

Comment: Because I'm using all() for a find() method where the key represents a unique user id. At least, that's how I see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to return some `users` variable from the callback of the `readFile` function which doesn't make any sense. You probably want to pass some callback to it which will be invoked when the file is read:

```
modules.exports = {
    all: function(done) {
        fs.readFile(users_file, function(err, data) {
            if (err) done(err, null);
            ...
            done(null, users);
        });
    }
};
```

and now when you are calling this `all` function you are not going to expect any return value from it, but you would rather pass a callback in which you will access the results. Just like that:

```
xxxx.all(function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // TODO: do something with the users parameter here.
});
```

instead of writing:

```
var users = xxxx.all();
```

which will never work because `all` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Hmm I hadn't thought of it like that, but it makes a lot of sense. 

I come from a Ruby on Rails background, so I was hoping to simply get all users by doing something like users = user.all();

Comment: yeah, in nodejs everything is asynchronous, so don't think in terms of return values from functions, but rather in terms of callbacks that will be executed at some future time.

Comment: Yeah, this has been the struggle :) Thanks so much!